# Running a SQL statement to JOIN two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

[Table RIDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z4K3.png)
[image: RIDING]

[Table ROUTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jHZ9.png)
[image: ROUTE]

[ambiguous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kad0C.png)

I am trying to do a join of the TIME and place it between Route_ID and starting_destination on my Route table.

This is the SQL I've come up with so far,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Route
INNER JOIN Riding
```

I have never done a join before and am not sure which one to use.

Comment: I added a new image to the question, the query is too broad and am trying to narrow it down to TRAIN_ID, FINAL_DESTINATION, STARTING_DESTINATION and Time from the Riding table. Am I using the proper join for this purpose? I can use any join it does not have to be inner

Comment: You need to mention table name with train_id column. I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Thank You, how can I give you +1?

Comment: If it helped you can accept my answer by clicking the green check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  add on clause.

```
SELECT Route.train_id,final_destination, starting_destination, riding.time FROM Route INNER JOIN Riding on Route.train_id = Riding.train_id
```

Train_id is available in both the table. So it's ambiguous to mention only column name. Oracle would not know which table you are referencing. You need to mention table name for common columns.

Comment: @Aaron Selenica